# delete data from a form into a database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to delete data from a form into a database. But my code give me an error "Could not delete data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'WHERE id = 3'` at line 1".

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>



<!--$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","firstphp");*/-->

<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if(!$con)
{
  die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}

$id = $_POST["id"];

$sql = "DELETE employee ".
       "WHERE id = $id" ;

mysql_select_db('firstphp');
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
if(!$result)
{
  die("Could not delete data: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
mysql_close($con);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Employee ID</td>
<td><input name="id" type="text" id="id"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "DELETE FROM employee WHERE id = $id"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error lies in the SQL Syntax as u can read.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM employee ".
       "WHERE id = ".$id ;
```

if the ´id´ is a VARCHAR do this:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM employee ".
       "WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

should work.

Comment: For future readers: this is a dangerously insecure answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM employee WHERE id = $id" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM employee "."WHERE id = $id" ;
```

you have missed FROM in the sql query

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM employee WHERE id =".$id ;
```

Comment: Seems vulnerable for SQL-injection